# I used the updater on ubuntu 14.04 and when I restarted, it still shows 14.04 and Chromium no longer works, how do I get 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, chromium, browser

I have a Dell Inspiron 3552 that came with ubuntu 14.04.  I used the updater to get updates (hoping to get 16.04) and when I restarted the computer, following the prompts, it still showed version 14.04 and Chromium no longer works.  how do I get the 16.04 version and should I scrap Chromium and download another browser?

Answer (score 0):

You will not upgrade to a new release this way.

The correct command is `do-release-upgrade`.

Also I don't recommend to upgrade a pre-installed Dell Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. It causes lot's of trouble in many cases.

The recommended way is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

Regarding Google Chrome and probably other Chromium based browsers, they don't support 32-bit systems any more. You can use Firefox.

Comment: so how do I do a fresh install of 16.04?  or should I not bother, I mean, does it make a lot of difference?  maybe I can wait till 18.04?

Comment: but in general, I should just download firefox because Chromium doesn't work anymore with ubuntu 14.04--is that right?

Comment: You don't need to download anything. Firefox is already installed.

Comment: no, there is no firefox in my computer.

Comment: Then you are not using Ubuntu. Everyone who installs Ubuntu has Firefox. I see that it may a customized version. The you can always install Firefox by `sudo apt install firefox`.

Comment: I bought the dell that comes with ubuntu 14.04 and I installed it when I first got the computer.  when I turn it on, it says ubuntu 14.04 so I pretty sure I'm using ubuntu.  the first thing I did was look for firefox but it doesn't have it, only Chromium and a generic browser called "browser"

Comment: This means that Dell removed Firefox for some reason. I suggest installing a fresh vanilla 16.04. You can also install Firefox to the existing system.

Comment: how do I do a fresh install of 16.04?  I went to the ubuntu website and downloaded the 16.04 onto a disk and I tried following instructions about how to boot from the disk and couldn't figure it out, sounds really complicated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu If it is too comlicated for you, then install Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

As with any major operation, the first thing to do is backup any data you can't afford to lose. Although problems are rare they do occur.

to check which version will be applied, open a terminal and do:
`sudo do-release-upgrade -c`

to make it easier on the dependency resolver, be sure your current software is up to date:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

next clean up apt:
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

now you are ready to upgrade:
`sudo do-release-upgrade`

the installer should give a list of actions it will perform. read over the removal list carefully before committing to the upgrade.

Comment: I opened a terminal and put in do-distribution-upgrade -c and hit enter and got command not found ????

Comment: you need `sudo`  before it, sorry